# Bash: Explain the following the redirection cases

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I am reading [BashFAQ/002](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002) and came accross the following redirection cases. I have written my understanding with each case so please comment if I am wrong.

**Case 1**

```
output=$(command 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
```

Redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and than redirect `stdout` to `tty`. So, now both `stdout and stderr` redirects/output to terminal.

**Case 2**

```
output=$(command 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

Redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and than redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null`. Although I don't understand the point of doing this because now both `stderr and stdout` are discarded.

**Case 3**

```
output=$(command 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3-)
```

No, idea whatsoever whats happening here. I am not aware of `fd 3`.

**Case 4**

```
exec 3>&1 
output=$(command 2>&1 1>&3)
exec 3>&-
```

No, idea again.

So, can someone explain to me in detail the case#3 and case#4 and point me to the relevant documentation.

Comment: case 2:  'because now both stderr and stdout are discarded' - _that_ is the point of sending to /dev/null - discarding it

Comment: ^ not true. only stdout is redirected to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

Sending data to /dev/null indicates you don't care about the result (for instance, you just wanted to perform the operation)

Case 3 & 4: Each open file gets assigned a file descriptor.  The file descriptors for stdin, stdout, and stderr are 0, 1, and 2, respectively. For opening additional files, there remain descriptors 3 to 9. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Answer (score 2):

Case 1 and 2 don't do what you describe. In both those cases, `stderr` will be redirected to whatever `stdout` was linked to *before* `stdout` is redirected. i.e. in both those cases, `output` will store whatever `command` printed to `stderr`, and `stdout` is redirected to `/dev/tty` and `/dev/null` respectively. (See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23964/why-is-redirecting-stderr-to-dev-null-done-this-way), and the bash documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections))

`3` is just another file descriptor. There's nothing "magic" about it, the application/command/script define what it does.

For the forms with a `-` at the end, see the bash documentation under REDIRECTION and [Moving File Descriptors](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Moving-File-Descriptors), and [A Detailed Introduction to I/O and I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ioredirintro.html).

Comment: Thanks, will get back after reading the relevant documentation links.

Answer (score 1):

`2>&1` means you are duplicating stdout on stderr, i.e. you're redirecting stderr to where stdout is currently pointing at (let's simplify this by calling it "stdout's location").

This redirection is analogous to pass by value, and not pass by reference. So when you redirect stdout later, stderr does not get redirect too.

To illustrate, with `output=$(command 2>&1 >/dev/tty)`

- `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout's location.
- `>/dev/tty` redirects stdout to `/dev/tty`, whereas stderr remains unchanged.

---

FDs 3-9 can be used however you want, e.g. to temporarily store other FD's location or to point at files.

In Case 3, FD3 is used to temporarily store stderr's location while stderr's location and stdout's location are being switched.

**Note**:

- `1>&3-` copies FD3's location to stderr, then closes FD3
- `3>&-` closes FD3

Case 4 is pretty much the same as Case 3. `exec 3>&1` as used in Case 4 would have effect on all subsequent commands in the current shell (until closed with `exec 3>&-`), whereas the `3>&1` in Case 3 limits the redirection to `command` only.